# What's the vertical line between the letters called in CSS?

Tags: css, caret

This vertical line appeared when I clicked on the text.  I'm wondering if it is caused by the browser default styling or something in my stylesheet.  Is there anyone who knows what is the CSS property of this thing called?  Because I want to remove it.

[image: A green copyright sign (©) is seen on a pale, marble-like background, below which there is the text: ‘A| history of everything you copy’ set in a sans-serif font.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s called the caret.  But it’s not actually a CSS style.

You have probably inadvertently enabled caret browsing mode in your browser by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>.  Just press the key again to disable it.  This works in Firefox and in Chromium.

This feature is in fact so notorious for confusing users that browsers usually display a prompt when it is enabled.  The prompt can be disabled, in which case it becomes much easier to accidentally enable the mode.